# Sveltekit standalone endpoint issue

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to set up a standalone endpoint and then loop through it on a svelte page.

The console says it doesn't recognize "phones" as an object but when I log it out it looks like an object. I am stuck. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Code below.

page/__data.json:

```
{"phones":[{"id":1,"name":"iphone","price":123},{"id":2,"name":"iphone2","price":1234}]}
```

standalone.svelte:

```
<script context="module">
    export const load = async ({ fetch }) => {
        const res = await fetch("page/__data.json", {
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json"
            }
        });
        const phones = await res.json();
        return {
            props: {
                phones
            }
        }
    }
 
</script>


<script>
    export let phones;
</script>


{#each phones as phone}
   {phone.name}<br>
   {phone.price}<br>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that object is what you get from fetch, your code should probably be:

```js
const { phones } = await res.json();
// or
const json = await res.json();
const phones = json.phones;
```